# log4j config issue with socket appender

Tags: spring, log4j

It shows error when i trying to run the project using socket appender.But it is working fine when i am printing logs on a file.

```
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.    
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

Comment: How about adding the actual configuration....

Comment: problem solved- Issue was log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, server was missing in log4j config file .Thanks